# Nav Bar with Centered Logo

Tags: html, css, center, nav

So I've seen several answers to this question here and around the web, but I cannot seem to get it to work for me.

This is first time coding anything beyond the basics (and I only have a week to do it for a class).
 I've tried using two ul's with a `div` in the middle, but one `ul` with the logo image as a `li` seems to get me the closest. My problem is that while the logo is actually centered, I can't get the other `li's` to be centered around it while getting the whole nav bar itself to be centered on the page. 
The site will also have to be `responsive` (a whole other issue, I know, but I don't want to gunk up my code with a solution that will be incompatible with a `responsive design`). I'm also not sure hoe to get the logo and the other li's to be vertically centered. I've tried `'vertical-align: middle'` but without any success. Thanks so much for any help.

Here's my HTML.

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="navright"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="navright"><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="Images/pantry logo.png" width="536" height="348"/></a></li>
                <li class="navleft"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li class="navleft"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>  
       </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS.

```
.header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }

div ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 60px 70px 40px 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    }

div ul li a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    }

.nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    }

#logo a img {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

You can go to the site [[here]](http://www.thomashall.idesignclass.com/).

Comment: Why are you using list tags... lists only really belong in headers when creating a drop-down menu...

Comment: This is just the way I have seen most others create a nav bar. If you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: I wouldn't add the logo in the main nav. Place it outside of the nav unless you have some sort of odd requirement that it be there.

Comment: @innerurge1 It's the way I have it mocked up and I pretty much have to keep it this way for the grade.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't mean visual have to be there. Does it have to be there in the code, because that seems odd. Would this work http://jsfiddle.net/eZg6x/. If not, I can work with the HTML you have.

Comment: also, do you have the mock up as an image?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why are you using logo in menu. You can place it to the center using `position` property. Using your current structure responsive version is also difficult.

For desktop version, add below code in your css

```
.nav ul li:nth-child(3){
    width:250px;
}
```

This will create a proper structure. But I would suggest, not to use current structure to center a logo. Separate logo from your menu and place it in separate div and position it using position property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update fiddle [**http://jsfiddle.net/JtfBP/**](http://jsfiddle.net/JtfBP/)

```
#logo {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the background of the header the logo instead and not make it repeat?

```
.header {
    width: 965px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background:url('Images/pantry logo.png') center;
    }
```

Use separate div layers instead of a ul list, that utilise the same div class (div.navigator) with the same height as the header, then use `display:float` and `float: left` in your css.

```
div.navigator {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 192px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 60px 70px 40px 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: float;
    float: left;
    }
```

so your header code is now:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">HOME</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">MENU</a></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></div>
</div>
```